# Regex Pattern Replacer

Tags: javascript, regex

```
input = ["hello \"shahrukh\" ", " hello \"dude \" "] ;

output = ' [hello \"shahrukh\", hello \"dude \" ]' ;
```

I basically need an `output` with all the double quotes removed if they are in the beginning or the end of an element in the `input array`. It's fine if the `output` is a `string`.

I tried using *Regex replacer* but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Pretty sure you are doing something wrong which can be accomplished properly if you explain why you want it.

Comment: If I well understand, you want to build a string from an array? But why? What are you trying to do? I'm pretty sure it's an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called `JSON.stringify()` to create a valid JSON string from an object or an array. The resulting string contains however the `"` you supposedly do not like. I think the easiest way to generate an *invalid* JSON string without `"` is to use the array method `.join()`.

```js
// using JSON.stringify()
var input = ["hello \"shahrukh\" ", " hello \"dude \" "];
console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
```

```js
// using array.join()
var input = ["hello \"shahrukh\" ", " hello \"dude \" "];
console.log("["+input.join()+"]");
```